# Easy stored procedure in mysql. error

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Trying to learn how to use store procedures in mysql, here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Trial1 (IN param1 INT, OUT param2 INT) SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO param2 FROM books WHERE id = param1; 

CALL Trial1(1,@a); SELECT @a;
```

It gives me back the following:

```
ERROR 1370 (42000): execute command denied to user 
''@'localhost' for routine 'test.Trial2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been logged in as anonymous user and that user does not have rights to do this, kindly login to a user such as root who has the privileges to do this and run the same command.

The command itself does not seem to have an error.

Comment: I am logging as root.. I should have all the privileges

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, are you saying this solved the problem ?

Comment: no.. even though i am logged as root it gives me back: ERROR 1370 (42000): execute command denied to user `''@'localhost' for routine 'test.Trial2` as if I was not logged as root but as anonymous

Comment: well show grants once logged as root shows that "root" has all the privileges needed however when I try to call the stored procedure i get that error message as I was not logged as root

Comment: Did we miss something you created Trial1 and called Trial2

Comment: Still the problem persists;

Comment: Ok I deleted everything and recreated it as root and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The user, that you are connecting to database with, lacks EXECUTE permission. Use `[GRANT][1]` command to resolve this.